# Scale images or separate files for better performace?

Tags: html, css

I have a Web App with two certain layouts.
Both are using same assets.
I want to know whether to use separate image files for each layout or to use the the background-size and positioning CSS properties with one image file only is more performant?
In first case, the app has approximately double size...

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: Up to 100KB and approximately 400x500px

Answer (score 0):

I would go with positioning with CSS as well as arranging the size